# Using an iPod 4G dock with an iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ipod, dock

When I bought my first iPod, a [4G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aIPod4G.jpg) model, in the box there were also a dock.
Can I use that dock, connected to a wall plug, to recharge my iPhone 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by dock, you mean a 30 pin dock connector, Yes Sure why not. It can be used with any other iPod , iPhone or iPads

Comment: Yes, it's the standard 30 pin dock that came in the iPod box. Thanks for the answer!